# React not loading from babel.rc file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, transpiler, ecmascript-2016

I am receiving a "module parse failed" error when trying to load my react app with Babel6 Stage-1. We initially ran browserify but I am now trying to port us completely to Babel6.

babel.rc file

```
{
"presets": ["stage-1", "react"],
"env": {
  "development": {
   "presets": ["react-hmre"]
}
}}
```

webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      loaders: ['babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    {
     test: /\.css$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'style!css'
   }]
  }
};
```

I have tried reading the documentation on Babel6 and it seems like I need to include react in my presets along with Stage-1.

I have done both and npm installed:

babel preset stage 1, babel preset react, and babel preset react hmre

Any ideas on how I can get react loading again?

Comment: Well firstly it's .babelrc, NOT babel.rc. Also make sure you have the es2015 preset: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding es2015 to the babel.rc file